# Running the specified ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate

I have a code so that when running, the **specified** **VC** is shown if the Switch is turned **on**.

But nothing happens and switch does **not save** its value after **restarting.**

PLS Help

**SettingsVC.swift**

```
@IBAction func switchChanged(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(sender.isOn, forKey: "isSwitchOn")
}
```

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    let isSwitchOn = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isSwitchOn")
    if isSwitchOn {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let VC2 = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController")
        self.window!.rootViewController = VC2;
    }
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}
```

**Edit:**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    Set.isOn =  UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isSwitchOn")

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Comment: Your IBAction is connected with your Switch?

Comment: @GiuseppeSapienza Yes

Comment: Can you try logging a few messages to see if your IBAction func is getting called, I'm also assuming you're aware that that delegate is only called when it's launched from not running.

Comment: @TPN1994 I managed to remake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice 2 things here:

#### AppDelegate.swift

Whenever you programatically adjust the window's root view controller, you need to call `window?.makeKeyAndVisible`to show the new screen.

#### UserDefaults

Currently, your code doesn't guarantee that user defaults is saved between restarts. `UserDefaults` will pick it's own time to save the data on disk, and if you quit your app before that happens, it won't save in time.

I believe that on the simulator, this always happens if you stop running the simulator via Xcode. Since this is fairly important behaviour, you might want to call `UserDefaults.standard.synchronize` to force a save.

Note that this call is usually done automatically for you in specific intervals; You're doing it explicitly because you can't afford to miss out on it.

Comment: I don't think synchronize is needed here. I could be wrong but I also know that it will be deprecated in the future.